# How to create an iOS-SDK for a specific functionality?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sdk

Currently i am working in a project where client wants the functionality in terms of framework which he can distributed to other people or developer.

Previously i have worked in many iOS app project but i have no idea of how to create it ?

So my question is what are the process to create it & what are the best practices one should follow for this process?

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial is involved around making a ios framework. This might help :

[building ios framework](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios)